# Why is this global variable not recognised in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, variables, global

Despite excessive googling I just don't get why my function doSomething does nothing in the situation below. Any idea why it doesn't work?

Many thanks, Gordon

```
var arrAttend=new object();
arrAttend["Blob"]='hello';

function doSomething() {
alert (arrAttend["Blob"]);
}
```

Comment: What is your output? How are you invoking `doSomething()`?

Comment: dosomething is invoked later in code by a mouseclick on a td object. I understand it is better to use an object as an associative array, hence the use of the object to store data - this is simply a test to try and make it work. Literal syntax suggestion below has worked.

Answer (score 4):

It's a typo, you should use `new Object` (capital O). Or use an [Object Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Object_literals):

```
var arrAttend = {Blob: 'hello'};

function doSomething() {
  alert (arrAttend.Blob);
}
```

Comment: +1 for literal, literals are always better (except when they're not, but here they are).

Comment: Thanks for this - capitalising made no difference, but the literal syntax did work! Am happy as long as I have A method :)

Answer (score 1):

Two problems :

- `object` isn't defined
- you don't call your function

Try this :

```
var arrAttend= {}; // that's the simplest way to create a new javascript object
arrAttend["Blob"]='hello';

function doSomething() {
   alert (arrAttend["Blob"]);
}
doSomething();
```

Note that the first kind of error is very easily found when you look at the console : an error is displayed. I'd suggest you to use developer tools (for example [Chrome's ones](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview)) so that you don't develop in the blind. BTW you'd see that using `console.log` instead of `alert` is most often more convenient.

Comment: the function call was elsewhere in a mouseclick. I tried your syntax above but if checked in the function arrAttend is undefined... Literal syntax above seems to have worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var arrAttend=new Object();
arrAttend["Blob"]='hello';

function doSomething() {
alert (arrAttend["Blob"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's typo error in your code. And an object should be used like follow -

```
var arrAttend= {
        name:'Blob'
    };
function doSomething() {
alert (arrAttend.name);
}
      doSomething();
```

Comment: You're defining `arrAttend` twice, first setting it to an empty object and then resetting it to a new object (constructed from the object literal).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// create object
var arrAttend=new Object();
arrAttend["Blob"]='hello';

function doSomething() {
alert (arrAttend["Blob"]);
}

// call function
doSomething();
```